# asp.net core not binding current User

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, jwt

`User.Claims` is empty if there is no
`[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]`
on the action, while i want to allow both logged in and annonymous users to have access to the action.

i am using asp.net core 2.0 with JWT authentication
here is my startup set up:

```
source.AddAuthentication(o => 
{
    o.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddJwtBearer(o => 
{
    o.TokenValidationParameters = JwtConfigs.ValidationParameters;
});
```

any ideas?

thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should also add

```
app.UseAuthentication();
```

in Configure method in your startup class (**before** UseMvc call in case you are using MVC)